# get last class text from ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, class, jsp

This is my jsp that get called through ajax.

```
<s:iterator var="result" value="all" id="result">
   <div class="Item">
       <span class="item_id" style="display:none"><s:property value="%{#result.id}"/></span>
   </div>
</s:iterator>
```

and this is my javascript that called it using jquery.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"test.jsp",
            data:"type="+type+"&start_id="+start_id,
            success:function(data){
                    item_id=$(data).find(".item_id").text();
                    console.log("item_id="+item_id);
                }
            });
```

my problem is i want to know the last item_id that i called. so that i can called the next one. How i do that? my code get me everything in that class item_id without any separator so i don't know what's my last id.

output example:

```
7910 ==> i only want 10.
```

Comment: `var item_id=$(data).find(".item_id").last().text();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following

item_id=$(data).find(".item_id:last").text();

instead of  item_id=$(data).find(".item_id").text();